# Jmeter+Captcha Unable to view

Tags: jmeter

In our application we are using "I am not a Robot Captcha".when we enable proxy and we access the application,  the captcha is not displayed. Because of this, we are not able to proceed with our scripting in Jmeter. Is there a way to make captcha visible while using Proxy?

Comment: You should disable the captcha for any tests anyway. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your issue is with HTTPS, did you add the jmeter generated certificate to accepted Authorities ?

Anyway, if it's recaptcha system you should not be able to automate it as it is made to block robots, and JMeter is a robot here.

So disable it anyway for your test.